# Copy range based on a date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA, my experience is basically record macros and adapt them a little bit, and i´ve been playing with a macro to copy a filtered range in sheet 1 based on a date value located in sheet 2 range "C42", the copy part is working

I have tried a couple of solutions i found on the internet but they don't work for me and I can't find the mistake (probably very simple but my lack of knowledge prevents me from finding it)

```
Sub CopyPaste

If Worksheets("Costos Médicos").Range("C42") =  Worksheets("CC1").Range("B101") Then 'both values are visually in date format "dd/mm/yyyy" but if changed to general give a number

    Call Cost1 'This is a macro currently working

    ElseIf Worksheets("Costos Médicos").Range("C42") =  Worksheets("CC1").Range("B102") Then

    Call Cost2 'This one also works fine

end if

End Sub
```

'I also tried this, I've tried declaring `cm` as long, string, date, but all returns `error 9` (again lack of knowledge)

```
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim cm0 As Range
    Dim cm1 As Range
    Dim cm2 As Range

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CC1")
    Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Costos Médicos")
    Set cm0 = src.Range("C42")  'This is the given date
    Set cm1 = tgt.Range("B101") 'This is a date
    Set cm2 = tgt.Range("B102") 'This is another date

If cm0 = cm1 Then
    Call Cost1 'this Works fine by itself
ElseIf cm0 = cm2 Then
    Call Cost2 'this also Works
End If
```

I think the problem is simple but can't find the answer, I have tried multiple solutions online but they usually are for far more complicated things that I don't understand. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `CLng()` to compare the serial date?  `If CLng(Worksheets("Costos Médicos").Range("C42")) = Clng(Worksheets("CC1").Range("B101")) Then`

Comment: returned an error 9 again in that very line, maybe i have to take a diferent aproach, like declaring the variables first maybe? i´ll keep looking, thanks! do you need the code for the called macro?

Comment: `If IsError(Evaluate("Costos Médicos!A1")) Then MsgBox "Costos Médicos not found"` and `If IsError(Evaluate("CC1!A1")) Then MsgBox "CC1 not found"` should tell you which sheet name is causing your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite sure that one of the Worksheet Names is typed incorrectly, as `Error 9` means that you called an element by name or position which is not present, so "out of range".

Change the names of the sheets to `x` and `y` for a test.

Concerning the dates: You do not need to worry about the formatting. Every whole day is represented by a whole number. Hours, Minutes etc. are fractions thereof. [Dates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-data-type) are stored as Floating point numbers (both in cells an in VBA) and can be compared to other dates or integers with no problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the solution Wolfgang Jacques provided was correct, but i actually found the mistake using Cyril´s code, the problem was a simple space in the name "CC1", was "CC1 ", i never would have noticed that simple mistake, thanks a lot!!! im new to the fórum so i dont really know how to thank properly to all of you.